# Secure way to mountimage share from container without privileged or SYS_ADMIN capability

Tags: kubernetes, mount

I want to enable mount inside my kubernetes pod (it's different with declaring volumemount as yaml file)

I found the ways to mount using

```
privileged: true
```

or

```
capabilities: 
  add:
    - SYS_ADMIN
```

on securityContext but, this permission could cause critical problems.

I've checked all of capabilities, but I found that only `SYS_ADMIN` have permission to mount.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

will there be another ways to mount inside pod?

Comment: I'm fairly sure, if you can mount(2) a filesystem, you can use it to escape the container (manually bind-mount the host's root directory, for example), so those permissions are not necessarily wrong.  I'd recommend trying to stay within Kubernetes's volume system rather than have your containers trying to mount things.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did found mount(2) inside CAP_SYS_ADMIN but, this function needs SYS_ADMIN's privilege. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html

Comment: @Kyroo0 Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393448/secure-way-to-mount-cifs-smb-share-from-container-without-privileged-flag-or-sys). It will help.